# framework not found React, inker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

I have updated RN to 0.61.5 and I get this error when i'm trying to build. As it seems at latest React native versions you cant add xcodeproj files to xcode and you can't add React at libraries. Is there any other way to link react to my project? My podile is this:

```html
 platform :ios, '9.1'

target 'App' do
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'FacebookSDK', '5.8'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.8'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.8'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.8'

  pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-mail', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-mail'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'react-native-idfa',  path: '../libs/@ptomasroos/react-native-idfa'
  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  pod 'react-native-wkwebview', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-wkwebview-reborn'
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'react-native-sensitive-info', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-sensitive-info'
  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path   => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
end
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `pod install`?

Comment: Yes of course .

Comment: can you open your workspace project again, clean and build again

Comment: Please delete IOS and Android folders and regenerate and then  try to link again by **react-native link **

Comment: Have you found a solution?